# Laravel page shows "This page isn’t working" instead of errors

Tags: laravel, windows, laravel-5, xampp

My laravel project is standing on xampp on windows. Whenever I make a critical error (a typo for example) i should get an error, but instead I'm seeing "This page isn’t working" in google chrome.

I've seen similar problems, but I have no idea how to fix this on Windows.

I have `APP_ENV=local` and `APP_DEBUG=true`.

Comment: Did you turn on laravel debug mode ?

Comment: I have a question and a suggestion. Firstly my suggestion for you is to use a cache killer plugin on chrome or clear cache manually on the browser(it will clear all the cache). My question is do you get a 404 error or a critical error that is formed by a typo on the controller code.

Comment: Please did you resolve this error? I have this same issue on termux

Comment: i was working on windows nad simply had the wrong php version installed for the project i was working on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was caused, because I was using the wrong PHP version.

I had XAMPP installed with `7.2.5` PHP version and had to downgrade to `7.1.13`.

Answer (score 7):

In your `.env` file, make sure you set `APP_DEBUG=true`

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Then run

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Sometimes, after running these two commands, Laravel still not reading the `env` configs, so what worked for me every time is to set the app to *maintenance mode* then set to *live* again.

`php artisan down` then in few seconds, run `php artisan up`.

*another cause:*

> Make sure in your env config, there are no spaces, if you have a value with spaces make sure to enclose it with quotes (" ").

Comment: I have done what you suggested, but the problem persists

Comment: @xEterno I updated my answer, try the `down` and `up` artisan commands.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on Laravel debug by change `.env` file

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

or in `config -> app.php` change this line:

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

And finally, clear laravel cache :

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Hope this helpfull

Comment: APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=emergency
I have it set like this. The problem persists even after the changes you suggested

Comment: Umh... In this case,  check laravel logs for more details may help. Check this file `storage->logs->laravel.log`. You see more promblems ?

Comment: Yes i did clear cache. In the laravel.log file i'm basically seeing the error that i should normally see in the browser.

Comment: Did you see this one in your composer.json ? `filp/whoops": "^2.1"` ? Run `composer install ` again then run `php artisan optimize
`

Comment: Oh... And remember set `APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug`

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turned out that i my php version was too recent for my the project i was working on i had xampp on php v 7.2.5 and had to downgrade to 7.1.13. The project was on laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1):

This error is because the server ran out of memory (Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted) before it could return an error. Try increasing your memory in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but my problem turned out to be an incorrect setup of Sentry.io in Laravel, that just crashed on error handling.

Sentry.io changed their integration code from version 2.x to 3.x. After consulting their docs and removing the old way of integration, the Laravel error page appeared again.

I hope others might find this useful.